# In AWS SageMaker, what's the difference between `sagemaker_runtime.invoke_endpoint` and `predictor.predict`?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I see there are two ways to trigger a model:

1. `sagemaker_runtime.invoke_endpoint`
2. `predictor.predict`

Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Boto3 `sagemaker_runtime.invoke_endpoint` maps to the low level [InvokeEndpoint API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html)

`predictor.predict` is the High level SDK call which is wrapping the `sagemaker_runtime.invoke_endpoint`.